# How to pass button value from to controller mvc

Tags: c#

i have a menu header with list of buttons defined somewhere else

```
  <div style="padding-bottom: 10px; float: right;">
@Html.DevExpress().Menu(settings =>
 {
settings.Name = "UsersMenu";
settings.ShowAsToolbar = true;
settings.ShowPopOutImages = DefaultBoolean.True;
settings.Items.Add("New", "btnHeaderNew");
settings.Items.Add("Edit", "btnHeaderEdit");
settings.Items.Add("Change Password", "btnChangePassword");
settings.Items.Add("Delete", "btnHeaderDelete");
settings.ClientSideEvents.ItemClick = "OnUsersHeaderMenuItemClick";
}).GetHtml()
```

now when clicking on btnChangePassword on undex it calls an ajax function which then pass userid and calls a controller  as follows

```
    if (e.item.name == "btnChangePassword") {

        var userId = UsersGrid.GetRowKey(UsersGrid.GetFocusedRowIndex());
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ChangePassword", "users")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            traditional: true,
            data: { ObjId: userId },
            success: function (index) {
                //UserCommodity_GridView.Refresh();
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + '; Status Text: ' + 
   textStatus + '; Error: ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

on my controller i want to check if btnChangePassword is click then return something in summary i want to pass a button value to a controller

```
     public ActionResult ChangePassword(string ObjId)
    {
        var user = db.Users.Where(c => c.Id == ObjId).SingleOrDefault();

        return null;

        //if btnChangePassword is clicked do something

    }
```

Comment: Is that `ObjId` contains string when passed to action method? What do you want to do after sending value to controller?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You've stated that you want to check if btnChangePassword has been clicked? But by the very nature of what you are doing, calling the ChangePassword controller, the btnChangePassword is being clicked.

Comment: I understand that this is DX menu which uses `ClientSideEvents.Click` to trigger client JS script (indicated by `e.item.name` property). But I think some important information are still missing.

Comment: i have 2 button which will call editform "edit" and "changepassword" through gridview my problem is on changepassword i want to have some input hidden so it only has information about changing password

Comment: Which input fields should be hidden? Is that editing user & changing password shares same view page? Please edit your question to provide any missing information.